# Mathematical/Comparison checks not working

Tags: php, comparison-operators

Please check below code.

```
$value1= 57.6;
$value2 = 177.6000 - 120.0000;
echo $value1.' '.$value2."<br/>";
var_dump($value1);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($value2);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($value1==$value2);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($value1>$value2);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump(57.6 > (177.6000 - 120.0000));
```

If you check there is no difference in $value1 and $value2 but when i am using $value1>$value2 it's satisfying the condition which shouldn't happen. Below is output

```
57.6 57.6
float(57.6)
float(57.6)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

PHP (like most programming languages, spreadsheets, etc) uses IEEE floating point numbers, which often can't represent decimal numbers exactly

If you subtract `$value1-$value2` you'll see that the result is tiny but not zero

In most cases, the advantages of the approximation outweigh the disadvantages; every now and then, though, the inaccuracies add up and cause real problems

The most common caveat is that `==` is pretty much useless for floats; instead, subtract the two values and check that the (absolute value of the) result is suitably small (less than some value, often vaguely called "epsilon")